# How to add plugin to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I tried to search google and follow do http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/step-by-step-guide-to-install-a-wordpress-plugin-for-beginners/. But My wordpress don't button add plugin.
[image]

Can you teach me how to fix it?

Comment: Mouseover Plugin panel and you should have an item "Add Plugin". If no, the functionalities of your WP account is restricted.

Answer (score 3):

**If you want plugins, you need to use WordPress.*org*, not WordPress.*com*.**

From the link you provided:

> If you are using WordPress.com, then you cannot install plugins.
>
> In order to use plugins, you will need to use self-hosted WordPress.org (See the differences between self hosted [WordPress.org vs WordPress.com](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/self-hosted-wordpress-org-vs-free-wordpress-com-infograph/)).

Executive summary: WordPress.com is slightly easier to get started with but doesn't support plugins.

> If you want to switch from WordPress.com to WordPress.org, then read our tutorial on [how to properly move from WordPress.com to WordPress.org](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-move-your-blog-from-wordpress-com-to-wordpress-org/).

Answer (score 0):

Click on 'Plugins', and then on the next page look at the very top to the right of the navigation menu. Do you see the button? The screenshot you provided does not cover that spot, and the navigation menu can sometimes bug up and not show submenu options.

Comment: I think because i use wordpress.com, so i don't install plugin

Answer (score 0):

As you got your answer but i want to clear more about it.

first of all you need to clear that with the help of www.wordpress.com you can create your blog but you can't do any extra customisation  on your blog. but if you want to do this:-

You need to download your wordpress from www.wordpress.org  org provides you full ability to use custom  themes or use custom plugins or you can create your own plugin or theme.

hope it will help you and for more information you can visit this link
https://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/

Answer (score 0):

There are several WordPress tutorial videos available for free on this site. Which cover How to add plugin to wordpress?

[How to add plugin to wordpress](http://interactivewebconcepts.com/index.php/wordpress-tutorials/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of installing a WordPress plugin is to use the plugin search. The only downside of this option is that a plugin must be in the WordPress plugin directory which is limited to only free plugins.

First thing you need to visit the Plugins » Add New page inside your WordPress admin area.
Find the plugin by typing the plugin name or the functionality you are looking for. After that, you will see a bunch of listings.

You can pick the plugin that is best, then click the ‘Install Now’ button next to it.

WordPress will now download and install the plugin for you. After this, you’ll notice the ‘Install Now’ button will change into the ‘Activate’ button. Then click on it. `It will activate`.

Here is my `blogging website` I develop recently. Below I mentioned all the plugins you should use to develop basic website.

[capablemachine.com](https://capablemachine.com/)

Plugins List :

- `Ad Inserter` - Ad management with many advanced advertising features to insert ads at optimal positions
- `Akismet Anti-Spam` - Akismet is quite possibly the best way in the world to protect your blog from spam. Your site is fully configured and being protected, even while you sleep.
- `AMP` - Enable AMP on your WordPress site, the WordPress way.
- `Chaty` - Chat with your website visitors via their favorite channels. Show a chat icon on the bottom of your site and communicate with your customers.
- `CoBlocks` - CoBlocks is a suite of professional page building content blocks for the WordPress Gutenberg block editor. Our blocks are hyper-focused on empowering makers to build beautifully rich pages in WordPress.
- `Elementor` -The Elementor Website Builder has it all: drag and drop page builder, pixel perfect design, mobile responsive editing, and more. Get started now!
- `Elementor - Header, Footer & Blocks` - This powerful plugin allows creating a custom header, footer with Elementor and display them on selected locations. You can also create custom Elementor blocks and place them anywhere on the website with a shortcode.
- `Getwid` - Extra Gutenberg blocks for building seamless and aesthetic websites in the WordPress block editor.
- `Gutenberg` - This is the development plugin for the new block editor in core. This plugin was installed by WordPress.com and provides features offered in your plan subscription.
- `Illustrations` - Illustrations Block, easy to customize SVGs from within the Editor
- `Jetpack by WordPress.com` - Bring the power of the WordPress.com cloud to your self-hosted WordPress. Jetpack enables you to connect your blog to a WordPress.com account to use the powerful features normally only available to WordPress.com users.
- `Kadence Blocks` – Gutenberg Blocks for Page Builder Features. Advanced Page Building Blocks for Gutenberg. Create custom column layouts, backgrounds, dual buttons, icons etc.
- `Layout Grid` - This plugin was installed by WordPress.com and provides features offered in your plan subscription.
- `LoftLoader` - An easy to use plugin to add an animated preloader to your website with fully customisations.
- `Mobile Menu` - An easy to use WordPress responsive mobile menu. Keep your mobile visitors engaged.
- `Page Optimize` - Optimizes JS and CSS for faster page load and render in the browser. This plugin was installed by WordPress.com and provides features offered in your plan subscription.
- `SyntaxHighlighter Evolved` - Easily post syntax-highlighted code to your site without having to modify the code at all. Uses Alex Gorbatchev's SyntaxHighlighter. Includes a new editor block.
- `WPFront Scroll Top` - Allows the visitor to easily scroll back to the top of the page.
- `Yoast SEO` - The first true all-in-one SEO solution for WordPress, including on-page content analysis, XML sitemaps and much more.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in wp-config file

define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',false);